# Binary Search vs. Sequential Search / Break-even Point

Tags: sorting, binary, sequential

I'm really struggling with this homework question. My professor does a terrible job of explaining anything. Help?

> There is a trade-off between sorting a list and then using binary search versus just using sequential search on an unsorted list. The choice depends on how many times the list will be searched. Assume that sequential search requires n comparisons in worst case, sorting requires n*log n comparisons, and binary search requires log n comparisons
>   in worst case (where log is log base 2, as we have discussed). Given an unsorted list of 1024 elements (i.e. log 1024 = 10), how many searches s would be required for sorting to be worthwhile? Suppose we consider the average case for sequential search requires n/2 comparisons. Now what is the break-even point for s?
>
> Hint: Write an expression for the number of comparisons required for s searches by each method; then set them equal and solve for s.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because qustions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: I apologize if my question is off-topic.  Just to clarify: I'm in an intro programming class and was being asked a math question.  I have very little math knowledge and didn't even know where to begin with this, so it was extremely helpful to have the question parsed out for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing the time that is needed to perform an initial sort (cost: `n*log(n)`) and subsequent binary search (cost: `log(n)`). So, if you want to search `s` times, you will pay an initial `n*log(n)` to sort the list and `log(n)` for each (binary) search. That is to say:

```
c1 = (n*log(n)) + (s*log(n)) = (n+s)*log(n)
```

Instead, if you perform linear search, there is no "initial cost", but each search will cost you `n`, so for `s` searches:

```
c2 = s*n
```

Obviously, for `s` and `n` small enough, `c2` is smaller because there is no such initial cost, but it *grows faster* than `c1`. At a certain point `c1` and `c2` will cross. That is to say, `c1 = c2`.

```
                                                                     n * log(n)
s * n = (n + s) * log(n) --> s * (n - log(n)) = n * log(n) --> s = ------------
                                                                     n - log(n)
```

Well, you now have to discuss the equation above. This plot should tell you everything:

[image]

Comment: Your graph is comparing *worst case* performance. it's more meaningful to use the expected costs, especially when looking for the trade-off threshold. The analysis is more complicated and depends on the distributions involved. It's not going to change the answer a lot, but will change the trade-off threshold a bit.

Answer (score 1):

As a hint: the work done to sort n and then do k binary searches is given by

> n log n + k log n

and the work required to do k sequential searches is

> n k

If n = 1,000, for what value of k will the second quantity be smaller than the first?

Hope this helps!